# WordPress: prevent caching of tinymce's custom buttons?

Tags: wordpress, tinymce

I'm following [this tutorial](http://brettterpstra.com/adding-a-tinymce-button/) on how to add a custom button to TinyMCE editor in WordPress. Trying to edit author's JS to include my functionality, yet it seems to have gotten cached. Article author has a hack for it (code snippet below), and it did work for the first time (the button is in the toolbar now), although it doesn't work for subsequent refreshes.

```
// "This will intercept the version check and increment the current version number by 3.
// It's the quick and dirty way to do it without messing with the settings directly..."
function my_refresh_mce($ver) {
  $ver += 3;
  return $ver;
}

add_filter( 'tiny_mce_version', 'my_refresh_mce');
```

What can I do to **disable this caching**?

Latest fresh WordPress localhost install, no plugins activated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out the 'no plugins activated' was not enough. Once I did a completely fresh install (**without** W3 Total Cache plugin), the issue disappeared.

Comment: Any other suggestions for this apart from fresh WP install? There must be at least a way to clear those nasty cache...